# Crafting a prompt to create an image from a specific angle in Stable Diffusion Automatic1111 web UI

Tags: prompt-design, stable-diffusion, automatic1111-sd-web-ui

How should I go about crafting a prompt to generate an object viewed from a specific angle in Stable Diffusion using the Automatic1111 web UI?

For example, if I wanted to generate an image of a bird flying upwards and away from the camera, viewed from the perspective of an observer on the ground. How would I craft the viewing angle of the prompt?

Comment: It may be useful to know which checkpoint you are using. It is possible that some will respond better to "viewed from below" or "bird flies overhead" and others may not.